# Commit and Push a Docker Container upon Exit

Tags: docker, automation

I currently use a docker container image of RStudio Server.

`docker run --rm -p 8787:8787 -e PASSWORD=MYPASSWORD -v /Users/carlos/Documents/IDE3/IDE3:/home/rstudio/IDE3 carlos1172/rstudio_server`

However whenever I make changes that I want to be saved as an image pushed to the docker repo, I need to do two commands:

`docker commit <container id> carlos1172/rstudio_server`
and
`docker push carlos1172/rstudio_server`

Is there any way to automate this?

I've read the documentation of docker commit and docker push and I can't seem to find a way to automate them.

Comment: You can (and really should) write a `Dockerfile` that describes how to build an image and commit that to source control.  There are several problems with `docker commit` and I'd avoid using it.

Comment: @DavidMaze So, for example if I want packages included in my RStudio image I'd need to add it manually to a Dockerfile and build a new image everytime?

Comment: You'd add it to a reproducible Dockerfile and get a reusable image, yes.  Note that this makes it easy to get a newer version of the original R image; just update your Dockerfile's `FROM` line and re-run `docker build`.